# cannot view visual designer in MonoDevelop

Tags: linux, monodevelop, designer

I cannot see any visual design tools in monodevelop. "Design" and "Source Code" buttons which are supposed to be at the bottom of a designer file. I checked if gtksharp is selected in the references. MonoDevelop is totally new to me and i am really stuck right now that i cannot find anything in google.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The designer does't show up for all files that contain GTK# classes, it only shows up for those which were created with designer support - the "Window", "Widget" and "Dialog" templates.

These templates are available if your project references GTK# - but the easiest way is to create a new GTK# Application project, which has the correct references, the app initialization boilerplate, and a designer window class (MainWindow.cs).

Comment: How can I attach the designer to an inherited Dialog class?